# Trying to read XML file into a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView where the user inputs data. The user can then save it as XML which gets picked up by another app watching for it. The User can also read any pre-existing files back into the DataGridView. The resulting saved XML looks like this (shortened version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
    <jet_texts>
        <message001>
            <line 1 />
            <line 2>e</line 2>
        </message001>

        <message002>
            <line 1>r</line 1>
            <line 2>t</line 2>
        </message002>

        <message003>
            <line 1 />
            <line 2 />
        </message003>

       <message004>
            <line 1>B</line 1>
            <line 2>A</line 2>
        </message004>

</jet_texts>
```

I try and read this back in by binding it as follows

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 ds.ReadXml(xml_file);
 dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

All I get is one line when I want 4 lines I even want the items that do not contain text to just be blank. I am not sure why I cannot get them as I tried everything I could think of but must have missed the the correct answer?

Comment: Its likely treating each Message001 etc as tables vs rows.  Your XML elements would need to have the same name to be considered repeating values in the next level up element jet_texts.  If you do not control the XML then you would likely need to do a linq to XML to extract all elements which contain message as the name under the jet_texts node.

Comment: If all else fails, the XmlReader class can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

May be yoe need a XML like this?

```
    <message>
        <line 1 />
        <line 2>e</line 2>
    </message>

    <message>
        <line 1>r</line 1>
        <line 2>t</line 2>
    </message>

    <message>
        <line 1 />
        <line 2 />
    </message>

   <message>
        <line 1>B</line 1>
        <line 2>A</line 2>
    </message>
```

Comment: I agree but unfortunately the customer needs the XML formatted their way as they read the file. so I am stuck with

Comment: Tried to transform the file before reading it into the dataset?